# jQuery, why the rewind playbackRate doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I got the fast forward playbackRate work fine. Now I try with the rewind part with negative number but it doesn't work. The w3school say to use negative number to rewind it.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_playbackrate.asp
Anyone can tell me what I did wrong?

Here my javascript worked code for fast forward,

```
$("#speed").click(function() { // button function for 3x fast speed forward
    video.playbackRate = 3.0;
});
```

Then here not success rewind code,

```
$("#negative").click(function() { // button function for rewind
    video.playbackRate = -3.0;
});
```

Comment: Side note: do NOT use w3schools... [read this](http://w3fools.com/).

Comment: I am surprised that w3schools is no good. Now I will have to blame my university for forcing me to use w3schools way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bplumb/h9EVQ/8/)**

Doesn't look like there is [complete browser support](http://www.digitaria.com/blogs/html5-video-skinning-tutorial-part-3-rewindfast-forward) for the playback rate option as far as rewind is concerned. You can fake it by using `setinterval` and subtracting the `currentTime` of the video.

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var intervalRewind;
$(video).on('play',function(){
    video.playbackRate = 1.0;
    clearInterval(intervalRewind);
});
$(video).on('pause',function(){
    video.playbackRate = 1.0;
    clearInterval(intervalRewind);
});
$("#speed").click(function() { // button function for 3x fast speed forward
    video.playbackRate = 3.0;
});
$("#negative").click(function() { // button function for rewind
   intervalRewind = setInterval(function(){
       video.playbackRate = 1.0;
       if(video.currentTime == 0){
           clearInterval(intervalRewind);
           video.pause();
       }
       else{
           video.currentTime += -.1;
       }
            },30);
});
```

I also added some extra listeners for the play and pause button to clear the interval. Might want to look into doing some toggling feature on the fast foward and rewind buttons as well.

Comment: it work fine but how do you know that if rewind can match the speed as fast forward playbackrate 3.0?

Comment: @StudentIT play around with the interval delay until you get about the same rewind feel as fast forward. I felt 30 was pretty close.

Comment: so if I have 1.5 instead of 3.0. The 30 will have to change but leave -.1 alone?

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure you test in a supported browser. I only found it to work on IE10 (though it's quite sloppy)
- Trying to set a negative value in [IE9 causes the video to pause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh924823%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (sets it to 0)
- It's supposed to work in chrome according to w3schools, but I haven't had luck there
- Should work on Safari too, though I haven't tested

  [example](http://jsbin.com/oveguy/4/edit)

Comment: This should be a comment since it does not answer the question.

Comment: @Dom can't comment on a question yet .. not enough rep points (I think)

Comment: It said it worked on Chrome but I tested it and it doesn't work at all. Only fast forward.

Answer (score 1):

This is, yet another, example of [w3school.com](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_playbackrate.asp) providing false information.   They forgot to point out that:

> When the element has a current media controller, the playbackRate
>   attribute is ignored and the current media controller's playbackRate
>   is used instead.
> *Source:* http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#playing-the-media-resource

After some testing using [this demo](http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html), it turns out, when the media controller is present, [`playbackRate`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#dom-media-playbackrate) must be greater than or equal to 0.  If `video.playbackRate < 0`, it simply won't play.

This means you cannot "rewind" using [`playbackRate`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#dom-media-playbackrate) when the media controller is present.  However, you can rewind the video by doing something like :

```
var _el = document.getElementById("video"); 
_el.currentTime -= 5;
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/sZVAq/3/

or

`<button onclick='video.currentTime-=5'>Rewind</button>`

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/sZVAq/2/

Comment: this is skip back rewind, I want framerate speed rewind, not skip back rewind.